# addSubview from xib - iOS 8 vs iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swift2

Here is my viewController to add (View is in a .Xib file)

```
class EmptyFeedViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var view_center: UIView!
   @IBOutlet weak var img_icon: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var lbl_description: UILabel!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayPale()
      lbl_description.textColor = UIColor.grayMeduim()
      lbl_description.text = "feed_empty".localizeFromFeedTable()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }
}
```

I add it like this from another viewController

```
let placeholderVC = EmptyFeedViewController()
addChildViewController(placeholderVC)
view_placeholder = placeholderVC.view
```

On iOS 9 it is working fine but on iOS 8 "lbl_description" is nil
How should I load my view for both OS ?

Comment: Those property names hurt my eyes.

Comment: Just a possible solution : Try taking the Xib file as a UIView itself, not as a UIViewController. And use addSubview method when calling it

Comment: dasdom Thanks, very helpful :|
Rob I am using a .xib here, not a storyboard, but yes that would work

@kaizoku How do I do that ? I still need a reference to the UIViewController later

Comment: according to the view lifecycle and lazy loading, you will be able to work with those outlets from your view goes into the navigation stack, briefly from/in `-viewWillAppear:` or later, earlier in the view lifecycle there is no guarantee those outlets were loaded for you, so in the `-viewDidLoad` you may find them `nil` – as you experienced already.

Comment: So the loading sequence has change between iOS8 and iOS9 ? Or was I just (very) lucky not to have the app crash until I test it on iOS8 (which I completely forgot to do until today - sham on me) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Xibs, in order to get the `IBOutlets` populated, you should create a new instance of your view controller using the designated initializer [`- initWithNibName:bundle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:)

```
let placeholderVC = EmptyFeedViewController(nibName: "EmptyFeedViewController",
                                             bundle: nil)
```

Comment: Works - of course
But it's a long line to put in code, and I want to be able to remove it quickly as soon as we stop supporting iOS 8 (yes I know, we still have time) so I  

     `init() {
         super.init(nibName: "EmptyFeedViewController", bundle: nil)
     }`


in my EmptyFeedViewController

Is that a okay solution ?

Comment: @Kireyin Sure! The important bit is that, when using Xibs, you call the `initWithNibName:bundle:` initializer. Hiding that inside your VC should not change the result :)

Comment: Hm yes of course. What I meant is: Is it a common enough way to do for people not being surprised by it ? Our properties naming convention is apparently already surprising enough :D